# How to install Garena in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

Im from Philippines South East Asia, Im using Ubuntu 18.04, how can I install Garena here? I would like to play League of Legends

Comment: If this answer is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Garena you can install with wine and notes found on [wineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=5335), There is a gold rating so it is possible to install.

But

> Currently supported games:
>
> Warcraft 3: The Frozen Throne, Warcraft 3: Reign of Chaos, Counter-Strike (1.5 , 1.6 , Source ), StarCraft: Brood War, Dawn of War, and Quake 4.

-> No League of Legends.

If you want League of Legends and feel the need to play from Linux have a look at this very very [long post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/comments/5ukgur/a_revised_guide_for_installing_league_of_legends/). It guides you through every setting you need. For a better gaming experience I would advice to install Windows with a dual boot and play from there or by installing Virtualbox, Windows in it, Garena in that and League of Legends in that.

There is another reason for that: as of a month ago they changed [their client](https://boards.pbe.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/bugs/WwW6FKPR-game-client-security-changes-now-live-on-pbe) and this restricts 3rd party applications. 99 out of 100 times this means [Wine is not useable](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflinux/comments/8bsg8k/league_is_soon_rip_on_linux/) since that is one of those and maintained by the community.